# why does rolling keep the value as null in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below function to calculate rolling average but this is somehow keeping the value as null if the col is null, do you know why?

```
def func_calculate_moving_average_3_6(df,cols):
    for col in cols:
        new_name_ma3 = 'ft_ma3_' + col
        df[new_name_ma3] = df[col].shift(1).rolling(12,min_periods=1).mean()
    return df
```

example:

```
df 


 value ft_ma3_value ft_ma6_value
    ...
    80  75.41666667
    80  76.25
    80  77.08333333
    80  77.91666667
    80  78.75
    85  79.58333333
    85  80.41666667
    85  80.83333333
    85  81.25
    85  81.66666667
    90  82.08333333
    95  82.91666667
    NaN NaN 
    95  84.16666667
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping the value as null if the col is null"? The function works when I try it, and in your example I don't see any 'nulls'.

Comment: if you look at second last position, value is null and i got ft_ma3 as null as well which is not correct and should be average of last 12

Comment: I'm still confused. A float column in a pandas dataframe cannot just have an empty value, it should be np.nan. And if it's np.nan, a rolling mean with `min_samples=1`, as you have it, should work fine. What's the actual output of printing `df` without edits?

Comment: edited the post, value after row 95  82.91666667 is NaN but if i have to get moving average of that row, it should not be ideally NaN i assume and should be average of last 12 value

Comment: As I mentioned above, if I create a dataframe with a `value` column with the data that you show above, your function returns a valid value for the row where `value` is `NaN`. I'm not sure why you get `NaN` there. You should always provide a reproduceable example (i.e., not just what results you get, but the data and everything necessary for others to get the same result as you in their tests).

Answer (score 0):

numpy.nanmean should help you, although not the most efficient way.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan]})

In [2]: df.rolling(3).apply(np.nanmean)
Out[2]: 
    A
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN
5 NaN

In [3]: df.rolling(3).mean()
Out[3]: 
    A
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN
5 NaN

In [4]: df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).apply(np.nanmean)
Out[4]: 
     A
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  5.0
4  5.0
5  5.0

In [5]: df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
Out[5]: 
     A
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  5.0
4  5.0
5  5.0
```

Comment: thanks! approach 4 and 5 looks same as per your results, whats difference between the 2?

Comment: using apply is slower. but you can test it on your data.